# sed command help. How to substitute a key word for the full path of the current working directory

Tags: sed

I'm currently using the 'sed' command (below) which searches for the word {{Title}} and replaces it with the current working directory ${PWD##*/}/.

```
sed -i "s/{{Title}}/${PWD##*/}/g" filename.x
```

How do I modify the above 'sed' command to work for the full path of the current working directory?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: `$PWD` instead of `${PWD##*/}`...?

Comment: When I do that, I get the following message: sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to 's'

Comment: when I simply use pwd, it actually substitutes it for pwd rather than the full path. It's part of a bash script.

Comment: Yes, its part of a bash script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `s` command to use a separator that is not part of the path.  Generally, `:` is not allowed in path names so it's safe to use here instead of `/`, like instead of:

```
s/expression/$PWD/
```

use

```
s:expression:$PWD:
```

Comment: This works ok. Also a side note: This char { must be escaped since it is also a regex char denoting regex groups.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou since `sed` is using BREs by default, it's actually the opposite: `{` should *not* be escaped as the BRE syntax is `\{i,j\}`.  They should only be escaped if using `-E` or `-r` to activate ERE.

Comment: Ahhh, yes i used -r indeed. Thanks for clarifying this out.